# Angular2 How to redirect to another component using Javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest, angular

I am trying to make a POST request using XMLHttpRequest and i want to redirect to another component if xhr request has been successful.

here is my code:

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgForm, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Control, CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgIf} from 'angular2/common'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http'
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from 'angular2/router'

export class StudentAdmissionForm{
    constructor (public router: Router){
    }

    makeFileRequest(data){

          var url = this.base_path_Service.base_path_student()+"student/";

          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

               var formData: any = new FormData(); 
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

               formData.append("image", this.studentDetails.image);           
               formData.append("first_name",this.studentDetails.first_name);
               formData.append("middle_name",this.studentDetails.middle_name);

               console.log(formData);  

                xhr.open("POST", url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')); 
                xhr.send(formData);
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function() 
                    {
                        console.log("status " + xhr.status);
                        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 201){
                            toastr.success('Created !');
                            var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            this.router.navigate(['../PreviousDetailsCmp', {first_name:res.student_id, student_id:res.id}]);
                        }

                    }
    }
}
```

The above code successfully executed. But my question is, what can i do in angular2 or javascript to redirect to the target.

I used `router.navigate` but chrome shows following error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

I also tried  `window.location = '/sidenav/PreviousDetailsCmp';` but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `=>` instead of `function` otherwise `this.` doesn't point to your component class anymore

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){ ... }
```

should be

```
xhr.onreadystatechange => () { ... }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details.